# How do i find a "\n" in a string?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I try to find a "\n" in a string. My code here is not working. What would be the right way? Thanks

```
    string text = "hello\nworld";

 for(int i=1; i<text.Length ;i++)
 {
    if
    (
     text[i-1]== '\\'
     &&
     text[i]== 'n'
    )
    {
        Debug.Log("break at: "+i);
    }
 }
```

Comment: \n is a newline and is usually represented by CRLF I believe, so you will need to look for char(13), char (10), or it might just be char(10), thinking that \r\n is crlf

Comment: @Charleh \n only represents the LF, \r is the CR

Comment: Yeah just realised that :) updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is not two characers. It is a two character representation of the value "Line Feed" (see the value for 10 on any ASCII chart). If you want to find the charactor you need to use both symbols in a single char like `'\n'`

Comment: See "9.4.4.4 Character literals" in the [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf). It says '\n' is an escape sequence for [U+000A LINE FEED (LF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm). Mentioning ASCII is misleading. .NET (and Java, JavaScript, HTML, XML, … NCHAR, NVARCHAR, …) use the UTF-16 encoding of [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

\n is a control character, try as condition

text[i] == '\n'

and init i = 0, not i = 1

Answer (score 0):

As correctly said '\n' is one character, representing a line feed. That means, the slash is the escape key, for example used to represent special whitespace characters (As \n is one). If you want to search for it you therefore have to search for it as a single character:

```
var text = "hello\nworld";
for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    if(text[i] == '\n')
        Debug.Log($"break at: {i}");
```